# How do i access global variable across all files

Tags: node.js

I have few variables like app key which i need to access across all files i need to have something like initializers which will initialize all my constants in one place and should be able to access across the application? any suggestions on how to implement this initializers in node. i don't want to require the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ideal way to do , preventing accidental damage to global configurations,

applicationConstants.js

```
 module.exports = { app_host : "example.com" , app_port:8080}
 Object.freeze(module.exports); // ensure protection against modification
```

app.js

```
 var appConstants = require('path_to_applicationConstants.js');
 Object.defineProperty(global, "appConstants", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
   value: appConstants 
});
```

Comment: When freezing the module export, you can also recursively do it for complex objects using deep-freeze module: https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze

Answer (score 2):

The Globals object should sort you out:
http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Answer (score -1):

Have a Look On This Code . it will clear the picture in your mind :

```
    public class MyConstants {

    public static final String PROFILE_ID = "profile_id";

    public static final String EMAIL_ID = "email_id";

}
```

And If You Want To Have some Variables Stored in your App for life time then you should use Shared Preferences of App.

Comment: is this java? i was asking how to implement in node

Comment: Sorry my mistake this solution is for Java .